# Drop table in teradata

Tags: c#, teradata

I tried to drop a table in Teradata database with C# if the table exist.

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("IF EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = '{0}')  
     BEGIN DROP TABLE '{0}' END", Customer.TableName);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the above always failed with :

> {"[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'IF' keyword."}

Second code i tried, the code below works !!!

```
cmd.CommandText = "select count (*) from Customer.TableName";
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.FieldCount > 0)
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        cmd.CommandText = "Drop table Customer.TableName";
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    }
```

However, it works only when got table exist. If the table Customer.TableName does not exist, then it will failed when undergo this

```
"select count (*) from Customer.TableName";
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbc.tables WHERE databasename = db_name 
AND tablename = table_name) THEN DROP TABLE table_name
```

First Try this in editor and then place in your .net c# code.

This will ensure existence of the table and if it exists it will delete it.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work.  if i just run the SELECT 1 FROM dbc.tables WHERE databasename = 'John' AND tablename = 'ctry', then it returns some data. But it failed when i apply the IF EXISTS () then drop table 'ctry'

Comment: {"[Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'IF' keyword."}

Comment: I have edited my post. The second solution i added works !! but it failed if it does not have table.

Comment: How to prevent the above not to fail when table not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with

```
"select count(*) from DBC.TABLES WHERE TABLENAME ='" + table.Split('.')[1] + "' and DatabaseName = '" + databasename+ "'"
```